# What does reference clock unit number mean in NTP?

Tags: ntp

I'm confused with NTP's reference clock unit number. I tried to find its meaning on ntp.org, but only found that its range is from 0-3 (defined in 127.127.t.u). What is the actual meaning of reference clock unit number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.2/refclock.htm)

> u is a unit number in the range 0-3 **used to distinguish multiple instances of clocks of the same type.**

Answer (score 0):

Better explanation for NTP reference clock driver types can be found here.

https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/refclock.html

Reference clocks are supported in the same way as ordinary NTP clients and use the same filter, select, cluster and combine algorithms. Drivers have addresses in the form 127.127.t.u, where t is the driver type and u is a unit number in the range 0-3 to distinguish multiple instances of the same driver.

Comment: How does this answer improve on the accepted answer?

Comment: It gives a link with proper reference

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/refclock.html](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/ntp/html/refclock.html) is the right place.  Routers do not set it to undisciplined when they are in fact undisciplined, BTW.

Also, be aware that for stratum 0 servers, it is interpreted differently--it is ASCII, such as figure 12 in rfc5905.  Cisco routers, if configured as stratum 0, will set this to "LOCL" which is not in the RFC.  On some systems, this will still be displayed in dotted decimal, "76.79.67.76".

Comment: An example from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66010127/ntp-server-behind-nat: #define NTP_REF_ID_GPS               *(uint32_t*)("GPS")